# CoreData predicate - keypath not found

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data object called `User` and another one called `Conversation`. I added a relationship between the two. The relationship is called `lastConversation`.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I also added it to the User.swift class as so:

```
@NSManaged public var lastConversation: Conversation?
```

Now i'm trying to use this property in order to predicate out from CoreData. Here is a sample of a predicate that doesn't work for me:

```
NSPredicate(format: "lastConversation.uid == 123")
```

But when I run it, it crashes and says:

```
SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000a5d5e0> , keypath lastConversation.uid not found in entity LPUserEntity with userInfo of (null)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but does the Conversation entity have a uid attribute?

Comment: It's a valid question :) but yes it is. It also happens if I use only the lastConversation.
And yes, i'm using the latest model version :)

Comment: Curious.  You’ve tried a clean build, restart Xcode, etc?

Comment: Forget about that predicate, if you fetch a conversation, can you see access its `lastConversation` property? Did you do a migration if needed of your core data model?

Comment: I did try to clean the build but it didn't work. However I did update xcode yesterday and didn't delete the derived data ‍♂️ Now its working